# HTTP 500 Error on php / Apache when uploading large files only

Tags: php, apache

The following error summary is displayed when trying to upload files of ~2GB's to my PHP on Apache application.

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
>   Detailed Error Information
>   Module    FastCgiModule
>   Notification  ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler   PHP53_via_FastCGI
>   Error Code    0x80004005

I've increased the parameters in the .ini file to no avail:

upload_max_filesize is "4096M"
post_max_size is "4096M"
memory_limit is "-1" for unlimited

Suggestions please?

Comment: get error log. increase php max_input_time,mmax_execution_time

Comment: Did you restart your `Apache`?